# Using Guzzle's isSuccessful method when catching exceptions

Tags: php, guzzle

I have recently used Guzzle to scrape a URL, and this works fine when there are no errors.

If however there is for example a 404, let's say

```
$response = $client->get('http://www.google.com/test')->send();
```

The manual ([Response Status Line](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/http-client/response.html#response-status-line)) suggests the above code will then allow me to call

```
$response->isSuccessful();
```

But `send()` throws a `ClientErrorResponseException` when there is an error receiving the request. The exception thrown is as follows

```
Guzzle\Http\Exception\ClientErrorResponseException
Client error response
  [status code] 404
  [reason phrase] Not Found
  [url] http://www.google.com/test
```

So, catching that exception obviously prevents my application halting, but then means I don't have a response object on which to call the various `isX` methods.

Clearly catching the exception gives me the same answer as `isSuccessful` to some degree, but some of the other methods on the aforementioned manual page would also be useful to use.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify `['exceptions' => FALSE]` as a request option. See
https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/master/docs/clients.rst#exceptions

Or, when you catch the exception, you can still get the response:

```
catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException $e) {
  $response = $e->getResponse();
}
```

http://guzzle3.readthedocs.org/http-client/client.html#exceptions

Kudos to both of the following for pointing this out on Github

- https://github.com/pjcdawkins
- https://github.com/mtdowling